# Wordpress Custom Post type show image for category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have been trying to get something to work, i have wordpress and also have a custom post type and custom taxonomies, basically i wanted it to show an image on a single post for certain categories but the rest will show a different image.

Here is my code anyone know why this is not working, all it shows is the second image.

```html
<?php   // Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms( 'story_category' );
if ( $terms == "global-freebies" || $terms == "usa-freebies" || $terms == "uk-freebies" ){ ?>
<center><span class="domain"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post_url ); ?>" target="_blank"><img width="250" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/freebie_button.jpg"></a></span></center>
<?php } else { ?>
<center><span class="domain"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post_url ); ?>" target="_blank"><img width="250" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/site_button.jpg"></a></span></center>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo out $terms? What is your output?

Comment: if i use eco i cannot seem to get the post URL to work properly so i am having to break the php so i can use html

Comment: basically i run a freebie site, and i also have tips on there as well on all the freebie categories i want a button that says get this freebie and on all the rest i want visit site button

Comment: I suggest commenting out your IF-statement for now and echo $terms; after you get the categories. Maybe the terms returned are not matching. Start there.

Comment: ok i fixed it if ( $terms == "global-freebies" i removed 1 = so it looks like if ( $terms = "global-freebies", obviously it was a bit to strict for it

Comment: hmmm...that does not look right, in PHP you need two == to compare.

Comment: ok that did work but not correct

Comment: You will get errors with that code, you need == and you really need to check your returned $terms.

Comment: strange $terms echos as $terms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141597/discussion-between-brian-and-cosmoonot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your issue:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'story_category' );
if ( $terms[0]->slug == "global-freebies" || $terms[0]->slug == "usa-freebies" || $terms[0]->slug == "uk-freebies"  ) :?>
<center><span class="domain"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post_url ); ?>" target="_blank"><img width="250" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/freebie_button.jpg"></a></span></center>
<?php else : ?>
<center><span class="domain"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post_url ); ?>" target="_blank"><img width="250" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/site_button.jpg"></a></span></center>
<?php endif;?>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: UPDATE: The condition was missing the key. Try again

Comment: Many thanks for all this help, the page now works but for some reason not reading from the custom taxonomies

Comment: Nice to help you my Developer friend!!